# Find the sum of the max values from all subarrays

Tags: arrays, subset

The question is - to find the sum of all maximum values from all subarrays. For instance, I have the array {2, 8, 4, 3, 5}, the solution will be 92. Where all of my subarrays are:

{2},{8},{4},{3},{5},

{2,8},{8,4},{4,3},{3,5},

{2,8,4},{8,4,3},{4,3,5},

{2,8,4,3},{8,4,3,5},

{2,8,4,3,5}

And all maximum values from all subarrays are:

2 - 8 - 4 - 3 - 5 -

8 - 8 - 4 - 5 -

8 - 8 - 5 -

8 - 8 -

8

Do you know the way to solve this problem in linear time complexity?

Comment: Yes, we know. But what is your attempt? Any piece of code you struggle with?

Comment: The question is how did you try to solve it.

Comment: Well, I tried to solve this problems in n^2, finding the all subarrays and getting the max value from each one, but unfortunately the key here is try to solve this in linear time

Comment: I get 192 for the given set. Did you mean to say 192 instead of 92? Anyway I don't know a solution, but one approach would be to look at this inductively. Start with a set of 1 element, either the biggest or smallest (I don't know which way works better), and add smaller or bigger elements one at a time until you get to the whole set.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a HomeWorkSolutionFactory. OP doesn't provide his/her attempt to solve the issue, the implementation he/she struggles with or any idea to be worth build the solution on.

Comment: @Rik4chu Since there are 2^n subsets, a naive solution seems to be 2^n instead of n^2.

Comment: @RobertDodier, you are right, but in this case the problems says about the all subarrays of consecutive elements. I forgot to say this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be very straightforward. See the following algorithm

```
sum = 0
max = 0
for every array 'arr' in the array of arrays
do
   for every element 'arri' in the array 'arr'
   do
      if arri >= max, max = arri
   end for
   max = 0
   sum = sum + max
end for
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I can't solve this problems in n^2 complexity time. I have to solve this problems in linear time.

Comment: This is not n^2 complexity. It is just n.

Comment: but getting the all subarrays from an array takes n, and to get the values from each subarray take other n, so this is n^2. In your code you have two for, this says us the you are trying this in n^2.